# How can I make Ball reset its position after scoring a goal in Pong?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a Pong game and i have no idea how can I make ball reset it's position after scoring a goal. Please help like really I need help I have seven days to complete this and convert this to Android but i havent even completed the main goal of the game. And I'm bad at English >:c

Answer (score 0):

You could store the original position of the ball in a variable at the start of the program then reset its position when a goal is scored.

For example, if you have a Monobehaviour attached to your ball GameObject:

```cs
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Vector3 originalPosition;

    Void Start()
    {
        originalPosition = transform.position;
    }

    public void ResetPosition()
    {
        transform.position = originalPosition;
    }
}
```

You can then reset the ball position by calling the `Ball.ResetPosition()` method.

Edit:
Don’t hesitate to provide more information about your current code structure/design if this answer doesn’t fit your desing.